# How to check if a Paragraph is in a Table or not in MS-Word macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The paragraph object in the Word has a property called Range.  Within this Range object has a property called Cells.

For paragraph that are not in a table, this property Paragraph.Range.Cells is set to "".  This can be seen in the Watches window in debug mode.

For paragraph that are in a table, the property Paragraph.Range.Cells has other properties in it, for example it has a property called Count.

I am using this property of Paragraph.Range.Cells to determine if the paragraph is in a table or not.  However, I cant seem to figure out how to test this.

For example, I cannot simply test like this...

If paragraph.Range.Cells <> Null Then.... or even 
If IsNull(paragraph.Range.Cells) Then ...

It throws a Run-time error '5907' There is no table at this location

So, how would I test for this?  thanks

Comment: See my answer below, and also the specific Err=5907 edited in later.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`Information` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820800%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
  'What ever you'd like to do
End If
```

Hence you don't need any manual error catching mechanisms.

Answer (score 15):

You can't call the Cells method unless the paragraph is in a table. You need to use a different method to determine whether the range is in a table.

You can use either...

```
paragraph.Range.Tables.Count > 0
```

...or...

```
paragraph.Range.Information(wdWithinTable)
```

Note that the second one looks more obvious, but is actually slower (only a problem if you're doing this inside a loop).

Comment: `paragraph.Range.Tables.Count > 0` did it (even with Word Interop  in .Net) :)

Comment: The paragraph.Range.Tables.Count > 0 is priceless information as opposed to paragraph.Range.Information(wdWithinTable). In a loop, the second option is not slower, it is downright painful, as a 3 column 3 row table can take up to 15 seconds to process. The preferred first option only takes milliseconds. Thanks for the tip as I spent hours trying to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

***Edited (if Err=) changed to (If Err<>)**

You can simply allow the error to happen and catch it using `OnError` statement

```
Dim ParagraphIsTable As Object

    OnError Resume Next        'allows errors to happen but execute next instruction
    ParagraphIsTable = paragraph.Range.Cells

  If Err <> 5907 Then '(this is to check for a specific error that might have happened)
          'No Error occured, this means that ParagraphIsTable variable must contain a value
          ' Do the rest of your code here
    Else
          ' an Error occured, this means that this is not a table
          ' do whatever
    End If
OnError Goto 0          ' This cancels the effect of OnError Resume Next
                  ' Which means if new errors happen, you will be prompt about them
```

Comment: +1 even tough it looks like you got your `'comments` mixed up. `If Err=5907 Then 'No Error occured`... Actually, error 5907 did occur.

Comment: I did correct it right after I read your comment. Thanks again, merci boucoup