# Parse word document in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I got a weird mission from a friend, to parse through a bunch of Word files and write certain parts of them to a text file for further processing.

VBscript is not my cup of tea so I'm not sure how to fit the pieces together.

The documents look like this:

```
Header
A lot of not interesting text
Table
Header
More boring text
Table
```

I want to parse the documents and get all the headers and table of contents out of it. I'm stepping step through the document with

```
For Each wPara In wd.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
```

And I think I know how to get the headers

```
If Left(wPara.Range.Style, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then
```

But I'm unsure of how to do the

```
Else if .. this paragraph belongs to a table..
```

So, any hint on how I could determine if a paragraph is part of a table or not would be nice.

Comment: VBScript is only a means to an end here. What you really need to look into is [Word's Document Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822963.aspx), specifically [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845117.aspx). I recommend that you develop in the VBA IDE that comes with MS Word (ALT+F11), because that has a decent integrated debugger, keyword completion, context-sensitive help, an object explorer as well as a REPL. The benefits of working in the IDE are considerable and translating from working VBA code to VBScript code is trivial.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering. I would definietly not choose VBScript if I could, the thing is that this will have to run as a batchjob every week without interaction, is it possible to trigger VBA script from a commandprompt?

Comment: VBScript and VBA are almost completely compatible. VBScript is dynamically typed, VBA has both dynamic and static types (that you are not required to use, though). It's perfectly possible to write working VBA code that can be copied to VBS and runs with little or no modification. Writing your code in the VBA IDE is a lot easier, especially if you don't know by heart the API you're developing against and need help from a debugger to see what you're doing. Of course there is a way to auto-start a VBA function upon opening a Word document, so if you wanted to you could stay within VBA.

Comment: Thanks again, the thing is that very few people are allowed to open this documents, that's why they have to be operated from the commandline. My idea was to use the SelectionObject to see if the current paragraph was part of a table or not (and then save it) but the SelectionObject seem to be non-existent in VBScript. I will play a little with the IDE instead

Comment: To make sure a paragraph is part of a table there are two approaches: Either look at its ancestors and see if any of them is a table. Or go through the tables of the document and select the paragraphs within them. That's what I would do, and that's what my hint above ("specifically this") was meant for.

Comment: Yes I noticed, and thats what I meant in my question (maybe unclear). I know how to step through the document and grab all headlines, and I know how to step through all the tables, but I have to get them in order. Every headline is connected to a table so I have to do it in the same loop. So.. if this is a headline = save it. If its part of a table = Save it.. Next

Comment: The enumerations in Word (tables, paragraphs, sections, etc.) are always strictly in document order. This should behave excatly how you would expect it.

Comment: I might be stupid (when its VBScript, yes) but I'm not getting it. I do use "For Each wPara In wd.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs" and check the Headline with "If Left(wPara.Range.Style, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then.." but I still don't know how to do a "Else if ..part of table". I tried using "Selection.Type" and "Selection.Type <> wdSelectionNormal" but the Selection object seem to be nonexistent

Comment: Make two functions that return true or false, call them `IsHeading()` and `IsInTable()`. Now you can do `For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs` and then `If IsHeading(p) or IsInTable(p) Then ...`. None of this is a VBScript problem, or a VBA problem, for that matter.

Comment: I don't think we speak the same language, my original question was exactly "How do I determine if the paragraph is part of a table". Not what I should name that function. Doing a "For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables " would not put them in order with their headings. And no, it's a question about accessing Word obejcts form VBscript

Comment: No, you are simply not listening to what I say. I told you [how to find if a paragraph is part of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058477/parse-word-document-in-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment46355624_29058477) and I told you that [paragraphs are enumerated strictly in document order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058477/parse-word-document-in-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment46355807_29058477). And I told you [how to put it all together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058477/parse-word-document-in-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment46356531_29058477).

Comment: Yes, thats correct, I focused on the "For Each table".. part. I'm looking in to how to get the ancestors, and I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: Forget about the "for each table" bit. That will naturally be dealt with if you're enumerating all document paragraphs anyway. (I thought you *only* wanted tables initially.)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, because I have no access to MS Word right now.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, Word, textfile, doc, para

' start Word instance, open doc ...
' start FileSystemObject instance, open textfile for output...

For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
    If IsHeading(para) Or IsInTable(para) Then 
        SaveToFile(textfile, para)
    End If
Next

Function IsHeading(para)
    IsHeading = para.OutlineLevel < 10
End Function

Function IsInTable(para)
    Dim p, dummy
    IsInTable = False

    Set p = para.Parent
    ' at some point p and p.Parent will both be the Word Application object
    Do While p Is Not p.Parent
        ' dirty check: if p is a table, calling a table object method will work
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dummy = obj.Cell(1, 1)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            IsInTable = True
            Exit Do
        Else 
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set p = p.Parent
    Loop
End Function
```

Obviously `SaveToFile` is something you'd implement yourself.

---

Since "is in table" is naturally defined as "the object's parent is a table", this is a perfect situation to use recursion (deconstructed a little further):

```
Function IsInTable(para)
    IsInTable = IsTable(para.Parent)
    If Not (IsInTable Or para Is para.Parent) Then 
        IsInTable = IsInTable(para.Parent)
    End If
End Function

Function IsTable(obj)
    Dim dummy
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dummy = obj.Cell(1, 1)
    IsTable = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Nice, but the IsInTable Function  eats all my memory and stops. But at least it's not giving me syntax errors so hopefully I'm close with this script

Comment: I put together an example in Word VBA, seem that the first para it sends in is "Myfilename.docx", and then the parent of that one ends up being "Microsoft Word" and it never becomes Nothing. Well, better make it run "Next" a little more often. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That it would become Nothing was one of the assumptions that I couldn't test. I wasn't reluctant to provide actual code for no reason. Instead of comparing to Nothing, compare it to the Word application, then.

Comment: Yes I got away from that one, seem that p.Cell 1,1 throws an error even if the paragraph is my "column1" in the table though. I'll see if I can find another way for testing

Comment: That was the other assumption that I could not test, but that's the general idea: In VBA, there is an actual type for tables and you can do an actual type check - in VBS, you can't. So assuming that you can't do type checks, how do you find out if an object is of a certain type? Trying to call some random method that only that type has is one of the ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, I've started to notice the differences between VBA and VBScript. I'm not even sure if there is a solution for this. Thanks for all the help along the road

Comment: Certainly there is a solution to this, and you're almost there. Depending on *what error* you get when you try to call `obj.Cell 1, 1`, maybe you have to call it as `Set temp = obj.Cell(1, 1)` (with parentheses), maybe you have to look at the error codes.

Comment: I get the "438", which I of course expect when it's not a column/row in my table.

Comment: I tried those solutions in VBA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436801/how-to-check-if-a-paragraph-is-in-a-table-or-not-in-ms-word-macro but they didn't trigger for a table either?

Comment: Let me guess, you don't have `Option Explicit` in place. I'm willing to bet that `wdWithInTable` is not defined in your VBScript. `Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` looks like what you need, but you will have to use [its numeric value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837003.aspx) (or define it as `Const wdWithInTable = 12` first).

Comment: Aah, think I got it. This one " Set p = para.Parent " seem to give p the value of "MyFile.docm" all the time.. which of course isn't a table

Comment: In any case this thread has devolved into an interactive debugging session that is very likely to be not helpful to anyone in the future. This is not the way things are supposed to go on SO. I have no Word and can post only untested code, which is painful and generally a waste of time. So I'm going to stop here.