# VBA WORD Identify if paragraph is a list or table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If (DocPara.style = "Title 1") Then
        ...
    Else

        (if DocPara is LIST then)
            ...
        (else if DocPara is TABLE then)
            ...
    End If
Next DocPara
```

So, I would need to know if the current paragraph is or not a LIST and a TABLE.

Thank You.

Comment: Related (not quite the same) – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436801/how-to-check-if-a-paragraph-is-in-a-table-or-not-in-ms-word-macro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test whether a paragraph range is in a table by getting the table count: if it's greater than zero (`Range.Tables.Count > 0`) then the range is in a table. There's also the older, WordBasic method: `Range.Information(wdWIthinTable) = true`.

For determining whether a range is part of a list (whether bullets or numbering) you can use `Range.ListFormat.ListType`. This returns a member of the `WdListType` enumeration. `wdListNoNumbering` is `0` - you can use either value. The other members of the enumeration can tell you whether it's bullets (and what kind) or numbers (what kind of list) if that information is of use.

I've changed the order for checking lists and tables, putting tables first on the assumption you need to know that primarily. (Checking for a list will then not happen.)

```
Sub CheckParaType()
    Dim DocPara As Word.Paragraph
    Dim rngPara As Word.Range       

  For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.paragraphs
    Set rngPara = DocPara.Range
    If (DocPara.style = "Title") Then
        Debug.Print "Style is OK"
    ElseIf rngPara.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "It's in a table"
    ElseIf rngPara.ListFormat.ListType <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "It's a list."
    Else
        Debug.Print "the paragraph is something else"
    End If
  Next DocPara
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a somewhat similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57911901/1232087). I was wondering if you would have some time to suggest a `possible` solution or a `work around` either in `c#` or in `VBA`. Thank you.