# C# to get second paragraph in a list item of a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.List

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Using `C#` I am trying to get all list items of a list in a `Microsoft WORD` document. The document has only one list as shown below. And the third item of the list contains a second paragraph.

**Question**: Following code is not getting the second paragraph of the third item of the list. What I may be missing and how can we get the second paragraph in the output (shown below)?

**NOTE**: I'm using `C#` but a `VBA` solution will also be fine.

**Snapshot of WORD document**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
Using System
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
....

static void Test()
{
    Word.Application oApp = new Word.Application();
    oApp.Visible = true;
    Word.Document oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\MyFolder\MyDoc.docx");
    string sList = "";

    Word.List oLst = oDoc.Lists[1];

    for (int j = 1; j <= oLst.ListParagraphs.Count; j++)
    {
        sList += oLst.ListParagraphs[j].Range.Text + "\n";
    }
    Console.Write(sList);
    sList = "";

    oDoc.Close(SaveChanges: Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    oApp.Quit();
}
```

**Snapshot of Output window in VS2019**

```
Item a
Item b
Item c
Item d
Item e
Item k
```

**Desired output**:

```
Item a
Item b
Item c
 A new paragraph in the list item c
Item d
Item e
Item k
```

**UPDATE**:

*The paragraph in `list item 3` was created in a usual way as follows*:

Create the first list item by clicking on `numbered list` button on the ribbon (shown in image below). Then type `Item a` and `hit Enter`. Second list item automatically gets created. There you type `Item b` and `hit Enter`. Third list item automatically gets created. And so on......

Now that all 6 items get created, you go back to `list item 3` where after the line `Item c` you `hit Enter`. A new list item as list item 4 gets created (and the remaining list items get renumbered - and the list has 7 items now). While still on the newly created list item 4, you then click on the `numbered list` button on the ribbon. The newly created list item 4 gets removed and gets replaced with a blank line where you type `A new paragraph in the list item c`. The list has 6 items now with a paragraph in list item 3.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is truly an independent paragraph - ANSI 13 (and not new lines - ANSI 11) then it *cannot* be a member of the list as far as Word is concerned. It's interrupting the list. That's why it's not included in the `ListParagraphs`.

What is possible is to create a standard `Range` object (doesn't differentiate between List and non-List paragraphs) and loop that. For example:

```
Word.List oLst = doc.Lists[1];
Word.Range startList = oLst.Range;
Word.Range endList = startList.Duplicate;
startList.End = endList.End;

for (int j = 1; j <= startList.Paragraphs.Count; j++)
{
    sList += startList.Paragraphs[j].Range.Text + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). The paragraph in question is indeed an independent paragraph and was created as explained in newly added UPDATE section of my post above. It seems to me that if we manually create a new line in list item, it becomes a truly independent paragraph - ANSI 13 (and not new lines - ANSI 11). Do you happen to know if there is a way to `manually` create a new paragraph in a list item that is still a part of the list item `when we access it programmatically`?

Comment: @nam I don't understand what you're asking at the end of your comment? Press Shift+Enter once or twice to add content that *visually* is separated from the list item, but still included in it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ CindyMeister Entering `Shift+Enter` creates new line - and this new line does indeed become a part of the list item. But I'm looking for a similar shortcut key that would create a new paragraph (not a new line) inside a list item - and that paragraph also becomes a part of the list item.

Comment: @nam Word's design does not support that. There's no way around it. Any reason the workaround in my answer isn't enough?

Comment: I also suspected that there's no way around it. After extracting lists from `WORD`, I need to convert those lists into a different format using Markdown language (similar to what WORD does when we save it as HTML). I think from your workaround I should be able figure out how to convert those those texts between new lines into paragraphs - if not, I'll post a new question.